# Opening edrawingsviewer files from java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, solidworks

I have an application that I run on a pc with a mouse, I want to launch edrawingsviewer with a particular file name from java and then when the user returns to the fullscreen app, if they haven't closed it I want to close it. This is what I've got so far for a quick demo but I cannot figure out what to put in the arguments in order to launch solidworks with a particular file.

```
package com.protocase.hmiclient.edrawings;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author DavidH
 */
public class EDrawingHelper {

    public static File[] getEDrawingsForJob(final String jobNumber) {
        File f = new File("\\\\itsugar\\www\\HMI\\POD EDRAWINGS");
        File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.startsWith(jobNumber) && (name.endsWith("EASM") || name.endsWith("EDRW"));
            }
        });
        return matchingFiles;
    }
    public static void test(String[] args) {
        File[] files = getEDrawingsForJob("G080111004-13162-1");
        for (File file : files){
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }
    public static void openEDrawingForFileName(String fileName){
        try {
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\SolidWorks Corp\\SolidWorks eDrawings (2)\\EModelViewer.exe  \\\\itsugar\\www\\HMI\\POD EDRAWINGS\\"+fileName);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton killButton = new JButton("KILL");
            killButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    process.destroy();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            frame.getContentPane().add(killButton);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openEDrawingForFileName("G080111004-13162-1 ASSEMBLY.EASM");
    }
}
```

I don't think this is a solidworks problem, I think this is just something I'm passing wrong or formatting wrong or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if running it through the FileProtocolHandler causes it to open fine.

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler \\\\itsugar\\www\\HMI\\POD EDRAWINGS\\"+fileName);
```